# Handling undefined types in the Telegram.org API schema, like "MessageMedia"

Tags: api, telegram

In the telegram.org api schema, the `message` type is defined as such:

> message#c09be45f flags:# out:flags.1?true mentioned:flags.4?true media_unread:flags.5?true silent:flags.13?true post:flags.14?true id:int from_id:flags.8?int to_id:Peer fwd_from:flags.2?MessageFwdHeader via_bot_id:flags.11?int reply_to_msg_id:flags.3?int date:int message:string media:flags.9?MessageMedia reply_markup:flags.6?ReplyMarkup entities:flags.7?Vector views:flags.10?int edit_date:flags.15?int = Message;

Notice the optional parameter `media:flags.9?MessageMedia` is defined as type `MessageMedia`. But nowhere is `MessageMedia` defined so my client does not know how to serialize/deserialize it.

What type is `MessageMedia`, and how do I deal with other types that might not be defined?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to understand this is that `media:flags.9?MessageMedia` represents a general type or as they say `a base type` which could be any of the following types:

```
messageMediaEmpty#3ded6320 = MessageMedia;
messageMediaPhoto#3d8ce53d photo:Photo caption:string = MessageMedia;
messageMediaGeo#56e0d474 geo:GeoPoint = MessageMedia;
messageMediaContact#5e7d2f39 phone_number:string first_name:string last_name:string user_id:int = MessageMedia;
messageMediaUnsupported#9f84f49e = MessageMedia;
messageMediaDocument#f3e02ea8 document:Document caption:string = MessageMedia;
messageMediaWebPage#a32dd600 webpage:WebPage = MessageMedia;
messageMediaVenue#7912b71f geo:GeoPoint title:string address:string provider:string venue_id:string = MessageMedia;
```

This pattern is common throughout Telegram API

Comment: But even base types must eventually resolve to a known type (Int, Long, String, etc) so they can be serialized/deserialized, right? In my case I'm currently deserializing, I'll worry about serializing later. If `MessageMedia` could be any of the above how do I know what type to deserialize?

Comment: @KennyCason deserializing is what i meant when you are reading the descriptor for a field like ```MessageMedia```, you will not find ```MessageMedia```, instead it would be one of the ```MessageMedia``` variants

Comment: How do I know which one? Is the id number returned by the server?

Comment: @KennyCason the type identifier will always be sent by the server.

Comment: @KennyCason you are decoding the byte-stream from Telegram in the order you receive it, and it is always encoded in the expected field order for the given type

Comment: Perhaps. I'll get back to this issue when I solve another question upstream from this. I'll create a separate question for it.

Comment: @KennyCason does that clarify things?

Comment: @KennyCason how well does Python handle byte parsing?

Comment: It's pretty good at it. Just cast the returned string as io.BytesIO and you can unpack one element at a time provided you know what data type to expect (int, string, etc), and that is known from the protocol.